# Drupal not connecting to Solr Server

Tags: search

I have setup Apache Solr version 5.5 and it runs fine when I test through my browser at `http://localhost:8983/solr/` but when I try to connect Drupal to this it throws the error:

[image]

I am getting some 404's in my logs also:

[image]

I don't know what is going wrong here, My Solr set up is fine so I just can't figure out why it doesn't connect to the Apache Solr Server.

Comment: Did you block ip's (or anly allowed `127.0.0.1`)? In that case it might be that you need to allow `::1` as well, or connect explicitly to the ipv4 version `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two things which I can think of.

1. Most SOLR installation guides advise you to edit `IPAccessHandler` in `server/etc/jetty.xml` to whitelist certain IP addresses. Often this is `127.0.0.1`, but that would prevent access from localhost via IPv6. So you maybe should also white label the IPv6 localhost address `::1`, or connect explicitly via IPv4 `127.0.0.1`.
2. Since SOLR 4.x you should also include your core name in the url. `Search API Solr` clearly states this. It might apply to Apache Solr module as well. This would mean your should enter a URL like: `http://localhost:8983/solr/<core name>`.

Comment: For solution 1 - I do not have any `IPAccessHandler` in my jetty.xml file, there are no ip addresses in this file either. 

For solution 2 - Adding my core name on the end results in a 404

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had to add my core name on the end of the path so like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name
```

It then connected to my Solr Server.

You also have to of-course ensure you have added a core from the Apache Solr interface by browsing to `http://localhost:8983/solr` > Core Admin > Add Core.

Comment: Isn't that exaclty what I proposed in #2?

Comment: @Neograph734 Yes it was